# Python collections.Counter, how to avoid double lookup

Tags: python, c++, dictionary, lookup

Trying to learn python here:

Suppose I have a very large Counter object where I want to change the value of a particular key if that value is greater than 0. So something like this:

```
from collections import Counter
...
A = Counter(huge_list)
...
if (A[some_key] > 0):
    ...
    A[some_key] -= 1
    ...
...
```

My question is, how do I avoid the double lookup for the same value A[some_key] ? The way that would have happened in C++ for example would be to return a reference to A[some_key] and then change the value pointed to by that reference, so probably something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  map<string, int> A = { {"key", 1}, {"key2", 2}};

  int &a = A["key"];
  if ( a > 0 ) {
       a--;
  }
  cout << A["key"] << endl;
}
```

which will happily print 0.

I believe the problem here is that the values of Counter are immutable objects; doing:

```
a = A[some_key]
```

"a" will be a reference to object A[some_key]. But a subsequent:

```
a-=1
```

will simply assign "a" to another int object with the same value lowered by one and A[some_key] will remain unchanged.

I suppose one solution would be to have a defaultdict with values that are lists of a single integer; lists are mutable therefore I could just delete the integer value and insert a new one decremented by 1 and A[some_key] would change this time. But is there a better way?

That probably also means the problem I'm describing here should be common for every iterable collection of immutable objects?

What are your thoughts?

Comment: it is dictionary and it use hash to get item so it works fast. You should test it for some big data to see if it fast enough for you. You can also use other modules - like `numpy` or `pandas` which uses code in C/C++/Forthran if you need something faster.

Comment: dict lookup is O(1) ...

Comment: Will you be adding keys after subtracting them?  If not, `+A` will return a counter containing only positive key counts, so you could simply subtract keys, allowing the count to go negative.

Comment: `if (A[some_key] > 0):` can be stated as: `if some_key in A:`

Comment: You would never worry about this in a language like Python, dict lookups are one of the fastest things in the language. If you are trying to optimize at that level, don't use Python, use C++. To put it in perspective, every time you reference a global variable, you are doing a dictionary lookup. When you do an attribute lookup, e.g. `some_object.some_attribute` you are doing potentially multiple dictionary lookups. Just don't worry about this if you are going to use Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga OK I didn't know that Counter(and dict) had O(1) lookup. However doesn't the problem persist for any other collection that does not have O(1)? What would be the way to solve the problem there?

Comment: Use a mutable object, as you've stated, but again, keep in mind, likely you are over-optimizing. What collection are you worried about?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga none really, I'm just trying to understand python :) I suppose such collections exist (simple lists for example, although I doubt anyone would use lists when lookups are common) so it would be useful to know what is the usual approach to solve the problem I'm describing here.

Comment: @burnedWood Python `list` objects have O(1) lookups as well, they are implemented as array lists. Although this could potentially be an issue with a `collections.deque`

Comment: @ChrisCharley would that not require the same lookup?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry, when I said "lookup" at that comment I meant searching for an object throughout the collection when we don't know at which position that object is.

Comment: If you're coming from a language like C++, your intuition about what's slow and what would be an optimization is going to be completely wrong for CPython. All the constant factors on the runtime costs of various operations are completely different from what you're used to, due to the overhead of a JITless implementation for a highly dynamic language.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid one of three lookups by using `max(0, ...)` instead of `if ... > 0: ...`.

```
>>> def f(c):
...     if c['a'] > 0:
...         c['a'] -= 1

>>> def g(c):
...     c['a'] = max(0, c['a'] - 1)

>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (c)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
              4 BINARY_SUBSCR
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
              8 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             10 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       28

  3          12 LOAD_FAST                0 (c)
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
             16 DUP_TOP_TWO
             18 BINARY_SUBSCR
             20 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             22 INPLACE_SUBTRACT
             24 ROT_THREE
             26 STORE_SUBSCR
             28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (max)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (c)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('a')
              8 BINARY_SUBSCR
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             12 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (c)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('a')
             20 STORE_SUBSCR
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

[`BINARY_SUBSCR`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_SUBSCR) reads `c['a']` and [`STORE_SUBSCR`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_SUBSCR) assigns to `c['a']`.

This was using `Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`.

---

But this does not mean that one or the other version is faster. You'll have to do some measurements to find out.

Comment: You could also avoid that lookup by saving `c['a']` to a variable and using `c['a'] = saved_value - 1`.

Comment: True... I didn't think so simple :(